# Initialize WebElements for part of a page

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm following the Page Object model approach. I’m working on implementing a `SearchResultsPage` where a bunch of search results are displayed. In thinking about this page, I would like to implement it in such a way that it would support a `getSearchResultByIndex(int index)` method. Ideally, I would like the return type of this method to be a `SearchResult`, which would be a mini-page object (aka panel) that encapsulates the functionality found on a search result item since there are a number of attributes of a search result that the user can interact with. I don’t see how to accomplish this though. I was hoping to find a method like `PageFactory.initElements()` that would take in the `WebDriver`, a `WebElement` or selector (that identified an individual search result), and an instance of my `SearchResult`, but haven’t seen anything.

For clarity. Here's the basic structure of a SearchResults page.

```
<div class="searchResultsContainer">
  <div class="searchResult">various internal fields to interact with/inspect</div>
  <div class="searchResult">various internal fields to interact with/inspect</div>
   ...
  <div class="searchResult">various internal fields to interact with/inspect</div>
</div>
```

It seems like this has to be a common problem out there that people have solved. I've used this "panel" notion for other common page elements like header, footer, etc, but never in the case where multiple instances of the same panel type are on the same page.

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I would approach it differently. I would split this into 2 page object classes.  One for `SearchResults`, and one for `SearchResultPage`.  The `SearchResults` would be the generic results list and actions you can take on those results.  Within that class you would add a method to click on an individual search result, to pop up the details of that result, that would be what returns your `SearchResultPage` object.

Here is a rough sketch of what that method could look like inside your `SearchResults` page object. Not sure what language you are using but this is in C# (Java would be similar, Python much different but you'll get the general idea):

```
    public SearchResultPage GetSearchResult()
    {
        // do something to click and show search details
        return new SearchResultPage(_driver);

    }
```

And then a skeleton of the `SearchResultPage` class object itself:

```
public class SearchResultPage
{

    IWebDriver _driver;
    
    // add whatever elements you want to work with specific to that single record view


    //constructor
    public SearchResultPage(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        _driver = driver;

    }
    
    // add whatever methods you want to interact with the elements in that view

}
```

The good thing about keeping the page objects separate in this case is `SearchResults` could actually be used in other areas of the application as well, if there are results on other pages that use the same elements etc. I find myself taking out common page elements (drop down menus, grids, etc) into their own objects all the time.  Otherwise you end up repeating a lot of code if you stick to strict Page Object model where common functionality exists on multiple pages.

Comment: I think you're missing the intent of the `SearchResult`. It is no the page you see when you click on a search result. It *is* the search result. Think of them as Google search results where each one has a title, a url, a description, other attributes.

Comment: But you would still click on them from the main "list" of results, no?  If not, then yea my rough solution wouldn't apply. I thought you would click on an individual item to see more details.

Comment: If I totally misunderstood your need then disregard, no worries.

Comment: I would want to be able to verify various fields of the individual search results before clicking into an individual search result to see something like an expanded cart item. In fact, a shopping cart would be another way to think of this. A cart of multiple items.

Comment: Couldn't you just add those verification methods to the `SearchResult` class itself? It sounds like you want to verify some data first, and then click into a individual record  to see more details? If that's the case my approach should still work.  Keep them as 2 separate classes/Page Objects.   To be honest there are lots of ways you could approach this.  Trial and error would be a good approach.  The goal being efficiency.

Comment: I don't think I've conveyed my need in a way that you're following, but I appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got this solved. I ended up abandoning `PageFactory.initElements()`, which I think I've learned is really key and likely an old-school way of implementing the page/object model. Adopting the use of `By` rather than `FindBy` seems to work much better as long as the appropriate conditional `WebDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(elementLocator))` is used.

After coming to this understanding, introducing the concept of a panel locator in my base `Panel` class allowed me to combine that locator with a `nth-of-type(idx)` locator to get things wired up and working as expected. Here's a simplified example of that in use in my `SearchResultsPage`:

```
public SearchResult getSearchResult(int idx) {
    SearchResult res = new SearchResult(getWebDriver(),
                By.cssSelector(".searchResultsContainer .seachResult:nth-of-type(" + idx + ")"));
    return res;
}
```

My `SearchResult` class then just has a number of `By` locators defined that essentially call `new ByChained(panelLocator, locator);`

So glad to have solved this!